# How do I use a Sinatra URL as parameter in route?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I am using Sinatra routes and I would like to interpret, if possible, a normal HTTP address as parameter in a route:

```
url http://somesite/blog/archives
```

where the route is:

```
/http://somesite/blog/archives
```

The code is:

```
get '/:url' do |u|  
(some code dealing with url)
```

The various '/' in the HTTP URL are creating problems.

The workaround I found is passing only the URL part represented by 'somesite' in the example above, and then using:

```
get '/:url' do |u|
buildUrl = "http://#{u}/blog/archives"
(some code dealing with url)
```

Is there a way to deal directly with the full URL?

Comment: What's your end goal?

Comment: webscraping the provided url: buildUrl. I process the provided page using nokogiri. Perhaps just not the usage of sinatra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not work as you specified. As you noticed, the slashes cause trouble. What you can do instead is pass the URL as a querystring param instead of part of the URL.

```
get '/example' do
  url = params[:url]
  # do code with url
end
```

Then you can crawl whatever you want by sending your data to `http://yoursite.com/example?url=http://example.com/blog/archives`

Comment: Note: this will not work if the site you're crawling also uses querystrings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you want, but, in general, Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class is useful for peeling apart URLs, munging them, then reconstructing them. If it's not sophisticated enough, the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem should fill in any missing holes:

```
require 'uri'
param = '/http://somesite/blog/archives'
scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = URI.split(param[1..-1])
=> ["http", nil, "somesite", nil, nil, "/blog/archives", nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: What i want is that, as a caller of the sinatra route, I pass the url which in the controller I want to parse (check the workaround in my original question). This means that the route is defined as /:url and the url itself has to be passed from the browser. The problem is that sinatra cannot match the / to a route when the browser has after it all the http url which I would like to be recognized as parameter. Therefore the need of the workaround I used. I can live with it, but good ideas are more than welcome. Thanx for your reply